# Telegram api in the application for android

Tags: android, api, telegram

I want to make an application for Android, the functionality of which will be directly related to the telegram api (not a bot, but a full-fledged api), but I do not understand how I can at least just log into my account, not to mention what to make requests. Documentation on working with the api through android applications I could not find. Please help me deal with this (just an example of how to send a message to the user will be enough)
*I used Google translator*

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look at [this link](https://www.androidmads.info/2017/11/telegram-bot-for-android.html?m=1).

Link: https://www.androidmads.info/2017/11/telegram-bot-for-android.html?m=1

Comment: Yes, it explains almost what I need, but it's a BOT api, I said I need a full-fledged telegram api